# Handle Session Timeout in .Net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, session-state

I am working on a website which is API based, client side is being developed in .Net MVC. For exception handling, I am using

```
 public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string action = "Index";
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();

            HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

            if (httpException != null)
            {


                switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
                {
                    case 404:
                        // page not found
                        action = "Error404";
                        break;
                    default:
                        action = "Index";
                        break;
                }

                // clear error on server
                Server.ClearError();
            }
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("/error/{0}", action));
        }
```

so for any exception thrown by try catch from Controller, the page redirects to error page.

Now I want that when session is expired it should redirect to Login page, How can I do that?

Right now what is happening is, after session expires, when I try to access the session value, it throws exception "`object reference not set to an instance of object`." then it redirects to the default error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this from inside a generic exception handler because - as you said - missing session variables simply throw a `NullReferenceException`. Perform a null check on the session variable from your controller:

```
Public ActionResult MyAction ()
{
    if (Session["myVariable"] == null)
    {
        RedirectToAction("SessionTimeOut", "Error");
    }

    ...

}
```

If you have session variables that should always exist unless the session has expired, you could try overriding the `OnActionExecuting` method for your controller and performing your null check in there. To do this for multiple controllers, define a `BaseController`, override its `OnActionExecuting` method and then inherit this in your other controllers.

Comment: I have already tried using this but in my case, the controllers are accessible with login and without login as well. When user is logged in he sees a menu with some additional items, and in this case when session expires and he clicks on item which is accessible after login, the `nullreferenceexception` is being thrown.

Comment: Try putting the [Authorize] attribute on the controller action that requires login - then handle the 401 error in your method like you did with the 404.

Comment: I am handling [Authorize] attribute from web.config. I have defined a controller in web.config on which it redirects id [Authorize] attribute is there and request is not authorized. Anyways, I am thinking to with your suggestion of overriding `OnActionExecuting`, in that case, will the `Ajax request` also be redirected if session expired, or for `AJAX` I have to use some separate method?

Comment: The Ajax request will be redirected - your browser won't. If you use the [Authorize] approach, you can handle the 401 response in your jQuery Ajax call as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991749/asp-net-mvc-custom-mechanism-to-handle-unauthorized-request