# message box before session get expired in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net mvc3 application user needs to fill long questionnair. After filling that user needs to click on either **save** or **submit** button. If user does not save data and keep screen ideal for more that 30 mins (session time out) data on page gets clear. user needs to fill data again
So to avoid this I want show user popup on screen before session gets expired and save the data. I have session timeout 30 mins. Could you please suggest me the way of doing this?

Comment: try [this](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/07/11/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout-aspnetmvc.aspx), [this](http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2012/02/28/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507224/handle-session-timeout-in-net-mvc-razor), seems same as your problem

Answer (score 0):

A client-side approach could be to use the *setTimeout()* function to display the alert.

```
function AlertSession(milliseconds) {
    setTimeout( milliseconds, "alert(' Your message ')" );

    //... or just send data to server to save it calling
    // a different function instead of "alert()"
}

<body onload="AlertSession(1080000)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just make an ajax request to the server at regular intervals to keep the session alive.